# Switch databases in a sharding environment

Tags: mongodb

I have a sharding environment and I need to switch beetwen different datasets (with several collections) with no unavailability time. There will be a daily load (millions of documents) that will create a new dataset, and once the load is completed, the new dataset will become the active dataset and the previous dataset (data loaded the previous day) will be the backup.

Since the client doesn't know which is the active dataset, the idea is to store the name of the active database and store it in a cache application layer, and then query to this dataset.

I've thought in having three DBs. One for the active database, one for the active DB and one for the backup DB. However, I am not sure if it is better to have three DBs or have just one with several collections, e.g.: collection1, collecion1_backup, collection2, collecion2_backup, etc. and one collection to store the active collections (regular or backup).

I would also thank any advice for improving this desing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about some load balancing:
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469397/mongodb-load-balancing-and-failover-of-query-routers

Comment: @Socrates could you please be more specific? Or show me an example of how to do it? Thanks a lot!